# Wird das Wort "Strippe" noch benutzt?

Tags: word-usage

Mir ist vor Kurzem aufgefallen, dass ich das Wort "Strippe" nur noch im Sinne vom Telefon ("an der Strippe hängen", "Quasselstrippe") gehört habe, und nie in seinem ürsprünglichen Sinne. Da man heute überall Handys bzw. nur schnurlose Telefone hat, wo der Hörer am Telefon nicht mehr gebunden ist, frage ich mich -- wird das Wort heute noch benutzt bzw. verstanden? Gibt es noch Gebiete außer Fachsprache wo das Wort benutzt werden kann?

Comment: Was ist denn der ursprüngliche Sinn?

Comment: @bernd_k Alles, was nicht direkt mit Telefon bzw. Telefonieren zu tun hat: Draht, Band, Schnur etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tatsächlich ist es so, das die *"Strippe"* ursprünglich ein Wort für Strick, Kordel, Bindfaden, Riemen etc. ist. Dazu schreiben die [Grimms](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=strippe)

> **STRIPPE**, f. , schlinge, schlaufe; riemen, strick, bindfaden. *nd.*
>   [...]
>    das in der bedeutung 'riemen; gedrehter strick, bindfaden' (s. u. 2) im 19. jh. vor allem von Berlin aus sich weiterverbreitete (s. Kluge-Götze etym. wb. 15774a) und dem das mnd. strop 'gedrehter strick' (Schiller-Lübben 4, 441) entspricht

Demnach hat das Wort seinen Ursprung aus dem [Niederdeutschen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache) und breitete sich über den [Mitteldeutschen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitteldeutsche_Sprachen_und_Dialekte) Sprachraum und sehr spät erst im 19. Jahrhundert auch in andere Regionen aus.

Heute versteht man unter einer Strippe hauptsächlich einen Draht, und speziell einen Telefondraht. Diese bildliche Verwendung wird auch in heutiger Zeit der drahtlosen Übertragung beibehalten:

> "*Wen hast Du denn an der Strippe?"* bedeutet *"Mit wem sprichst Du gerade am Telefon?"*

*Strippe* wird zwar noch regional in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung benutzt, die ist aber im Süden selten und dort nur im übertragenen Sinn anzutreffen. So wird zum Beispiel jemand, der als [graue Eminenz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graue_Eminenz) im Hintergrund Entscheidungen trifft, noch umgangssprachlich als *"Strippenzieher"* (häufiger aber als *"Drahtzieher"*) bezeichnet:

> Mit der Wirklichkeit des Schaeffler-Dramas haben diese Bilder freilich nur wenig zu tun. Bei Firmenübernahmen, dem Spiel vom Fressen und Gefressenwerden, hängt der Erfolg vor allem von den **Strippenziehern** im Hintergrund ab. Banker müssen Geld besorgen, Juristen die richtigen Verträge entwerfen.<sup>[Die Zeit 19/2009](http://www.zeit.de/2009/10/Schaeffler-Conti)</sup>

Auch der Beruf eines Elektrikers heißt im Jargon manchmal *"Strippenzieher"*, aber da sind wir wieder bei der Bedeutung *"Draht"*.

Comment: "Strippenzieher" kann aber auch abwertend gemeint sein.

Comment: Als Berliner kenne ich das Wort „Strippe“ in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung und stelle es mir sofort Berlinisch „Strüppe“ ausgesprochen vor.

Answer (score 5):

Regional (ich kenne es aus der Umgebung von Magdeburg) gibt es noch die Mundart Strippe für Gedärme.