# What is the origin of "Quasselstrippe"?

Tags: etymology

I'd like to know the origin of the word *Quasselstrippe*.

Is it the cord (*Strippe*) on the back of puppets on which you pull and they start to talk (*quasseln*)? Or is the origin something completely different?

Comment: No offense, but this Q looks like it could have been answered quickly by firing up a search engine...

Comment: Yeah indeed: search Google for `origin german quasselstrippe` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The composite noun *"Quasselstrippe"* is built from

- [quasseln](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=quasseln&view=1) (*to jabber*):

  > Reached German colloquial in 1900 from Berlin. It was built as an iteration from Low German *"quāsen"* (fressen, übermäßig essen, plaudern, schwatzen) (18. century), where the initial was changed from the Middle Low German *"dwāsen"* (Unsinn reden, irre reden, toll sein). <sup>[translated from DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=quasseln&view=1)</sup>
- [Strippe](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/wird-das-wort-strippe-noch-benutzt) (*cord*)

Therefore *"Quasselstrippe"* initially was used for a *"device on a cord to talk"*, i.e. a telephone (cf. http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Quasselstrippe). Later, and today when phones do not have a cord anymore, the meaning changed to describe a person who is talking too much.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, that's completely new to me. Thank you for reversing my edit. Hope you agree with my current edits.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know "Quasselstrippe" was a synonym for "telephone". 
Old telephones had a chord which can be translated to "Kabel". And "Strippe" is a synonym for "Kabel". 
But nowadays it is used for people who talk a lot and who can't stop talking.